# Unresolved external symol __im__RpcServerListn

Tags: visual-c++, linker

I already included `Rpc.h`, but I am still receiving `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __im__RpcServerListen@12 referenced in function _main`. Is there anything else I need to do to be able to call this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not enough to include the header file, that just tells the compiler about the types, functions and so on, that you want to use.

You also have to *link* with the relevant object files or libraries since they contain the actual code that you will be calling. You can tell this because the error starts with `LNK`, meaning you have a linker issue rather than a compiler one.

The actual files that you need to link to should be specified for the linking phase. For Windows RPC, this appears to be `rpcrt4.lib` (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).